# Session data doesn't seem to be persisting between routes

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local, passport-local-mongoose

I am using a middleware to check if a user is logged in to see certain pages which I've declared in a separate file from the route that I use to login. The middleware adds `req.originalUrl` to the `req.session.returnTo` field. I am using `passport.authenticate` in my login route to serialize a user onto the session but when it does so it takes away the `req.returnTo` field somehow ? I don't understand why.

middleware I'm using:

```
module.exports.isLoggedIn = (req, res, next) => {
    if(!req.isAuthenticated()){
        req.session.returnTo = req.originalUrl;
        req.flash('error', 'Must be Signed in first');
        res.redirect('/login');
    }
    else{
        next();
    }
}
```

This `req.returnTo` field does not show up when I try to use it in the login route:-

```
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', { failureFlash: true, failureRedirect: '/login' }), (req, res) => {
    req.flash('success', 'Welcome back !');
    const redirectUrl = req.session.returnTo || '/campgrounds';
    res.redirect(redirectUrl);
})
```

`redirectUrl` value is null

Answer (score 0):

Try by saving session data as bellow

```
    module.exports.isLoggedIn = (req, res, next) => {
    if(!req.isAuthenticated()){
        req.session.save(function(err) {
         // session saved         
        req.session.returnTo = req.originalUrl;
        })
        req.flash('error', 'Must be Signed in first');
        res.redirect('/login');
    }
    else{
        next();
    }
}
```

Comment: nope. It's still not working for me. :/